# Node.js Arguments Length method crash

Tags: node.js, v8, node-gyp

I am writing a node.js native bindings project and I am having some trouble debugging.

First, can anyone explain why the New function is being called in the require? The js code being called is `var Can = require('bindings')('CANInterface');` but results in an immediate exit with no errors. It shouldn't need to call New of the function yet, correct? Second, why is my code crashing on the following line of the New function?

```
cout << "Debug: Creating new CNI" << endl;

if (args.Length() != 1){ <<<< Crashes here <<<<
    cout << "Error: Invalid arguments length" << endl;
    return ThrowException(String::New("Expected one argument!"));
}
```

My output only prints

> Debug: Creating new CNI

and then immediately crashes with no errors or output.

Full code is available [here](https://github.com/tyduptyler13/CAN-Car).

Comment: Does any of this need to be in C++?

Comment: One thing to remember is that AFAIK (for node v0.10) you still can't have your NODE_MODULE()/binding.gyp "name" be the same as the basename of your cpp file. I've made a habit of just using somthing like "binding.cpp" instead.

Comment: @minitech Unfortunately yes. Its a binding for kvaser libraries.

Comment: @mscdex I will see what happens when I change the file to have a different name. Could you explain why that is true?

Comment: @TylerScott I don't recall offhand. Not sure if it is/was Windows-specific or gyp-specific or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the advice of some of my comments and moving just about everything around to more closely match the demo [here](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html), I have finally solved my issue and have a working implementation. Thank you to those in the questions that helped.